# How can i get my autosuggest to work with mysql

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete, autosuggest

i am trying to get some data out of mysql into my autosuggest in my javascript.
The problem is wird: The program runs fine, but when you write a value in the text box,  "empty"'s suggest pops up..

PHP:

```
  $sqldropdown = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT emd.m_field_id_8 FROM transactions as t
  left join exp_members as em on (t.cardid-10000000 = em.member_id) 
  left JOIN exp_member_data emd on em.member_id = emd.member_id group by emd.m_field_id_8 ASC");

  foreach ($sqldropdown->result_array() as $filterofresults) 
  {
  $samletdropdown[]=$filterofresults;
  }

  foreach ($samletdropdown as $key => $value) 
  {
  $victims[]= array($value['m_field_id_8']);
```

if change this line to this:       `$victims= array($value['m_field_id_8'])`; Only the last value in the array appears in my autosuggest. And then it works fine! But when i change it to an array. It will work but only empty suggestions will appear. 
      }

Javascript:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {

var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($victims); ?>;

$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
</script>
```

Html:

```
  </div>  

  <div class="span2 well " style="height:100px;">
  <p>
  <label for="tags">Search box: </label>

  <input type="text" id="tags" />
  </p>  

  </div>
```

What am i doing wrong? I realy hope you understand the question. If not feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation : http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

> There are two supported formats :
>
> An array of strings: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
>
> An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value:
>   "value1" }, ... ]

Therefore, you need to create your array like this:

```
  foreach ($samletdropdown as $key => $value) 
  {
      $data = array();
      $data['label'] = 'Label for data : '.key;
      $data['value'] = $value['m_field_id_8'];

      $victims[] = $data;

      //Or directly but without redefining a new array
      $victims[] = $value['m_field_id_8'];
  }
```

Before using like you already do :

```
var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($victims); ?>;
```